# Side tracks that come up during research

Tags: research-process

During the development of a research project, often one faces many possibilities - different methods one can employ, different ideas one can try, different problems one can try to focus, etc.. To be able to prevent the project losing its focus, we need to make certain choices. However, it would be interesting to note these alternative routes, as one can later need to come back to them.

What I usually do is to simply make a note book of these alternative routes, alternative methods/ideas I have to a corner of my lab book, but the issue is that I never come back and read my notes because I usually don't need to. And since I don't remember what kind of ideas I had in the past, it would be time-consuming to come back and read all my notes every single time.

Also, at the time I made a choice between many options, I would like to remember why I did one particular choice and not the others.

What are the best practices that I can use to record and remember these alternative routes, alternative methods, etc.?

Comment: I understand the general direction of this question, but not the specific issue/question. Are you looking for a more structured way of representing the choices, so that you don't need to read through a lot of unstructured text? "I would like to remember why I did one particular choice and not the others." Why don't you write that down as well?

Comment: @lighthousekeeper because in the end there will be a lot of text and idea spread over the whole document. I can't figure out how to make them more organized.

Comment: Have you considered having a table instead of plain text? For example, with the columns "question addressed", "options", "chosen option(s)", "reasons for choosing".

Comment: @lighthousekeeper not flexible enough to accommodate different types of needs. Plus, with the citations etc. it is not much feasible in terms of the presentation of the information. In a research project (experiments + theory), it is quite easy to get lost even on a table.

Comment: What kinds of needs? What is the issue with citations?

Answer (score 4):

I keep (for a pretty long time) my ideas, notes, excerpts, etc using [**Zettelcasten knowledge management system**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zettelkasten) (electronically, using [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md/)).

This allows me to create notes and links between them, organize hierarchically in several ways, represent in various fashions, revisit them in a structured or unstructured manner. I found this method to be very productive for both keeping the information in an accessible form, as well as to form and materialize **new ideas, which often come from research & development side tracks**.

This method also works well together with reference management systems, such as [Zotero](https://forum.obsidian.md/t/zotero-best-practices/164).

For completeness, about *zettelkasten* from Wiki:

> A *zettelkasten* consists of many individual notes with ideas and other
> short pieces of information that are taken down as they occur or are
> acquired. The notes may be numbered hierarchically so that new
> notes may be inserted at the appropriate place, and contain metadata
> to allow the note-taker to associate notes with each other. For
> example, notes may contain subject headings or tags that describe key
> aspects of the note, and they may reference other notes. The
> numbering, metadata, format and structure of the notes is subject to
> variation depending on the specific method employed.
>
> A *zettelkasten* may be created and used in a digital format, sometimes
> using personal knowledge management software. But it can be and has
> long been done on paper using index cards.
>
> The system not only allows a researcher to store and retrieve
> information related to their research, but has also been used to
> enhance creativity.

Comment: I use index cards, actually. Electronic versions have the potential downside that the can become obsolete. You also need a solid backup protocol. And anything in the cloud is subject to vanishing instantly. Paper endures.

Comment: @Buffy yep, solid backup control is crazy important if relying on electronic. But it gives a benefit of being able to use the system while in cafe, in a parc, or in another city. For me, it outweighs the downsides, and I sure pay a lot of attention to backups.

Comment: You can carry a small deck of index cards actually. See Hipster PDA here: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/a/1168/1293